# IIS Bulk legacy redirects

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, mapping

I have several dozens of urls which need to be redirected, and I don't want to create a rule for each of them and I cannot group them. Each url has its own redirect.

Is there a way in IIS to create a rule in which I put all these redirects?

Thanks

Comment: See rewrite maps, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @iusmar If your issue is solved then post the solution and mark the suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open IIS
2. Assuming you have URL Rewrite module installed, double click on it
3. On the right side, on Actions, under Manage Server Variables there's View Rewrite Maps.
4. On the right side, Add Rewrite Map, Fill in a proper name (eg: LegacyRedirects)
5. Open the newly created rewrite map, and on the right side, there's "Add Mapping Entry":

Original value: source (eg: /contact-us/europe/germany)
New value: destination (eg: /)

The above example redirects the traffic from the page with source path to the root page.